# Removing cout causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, eclipse

this is my code:

```
template <typename T>
struct Node
{
   T info;       
   Node<T>* next; 
};


template<typename T>
struct List
{
   Node<T>* n;
   int curr;
};

List<T> listCreate()
{
   List<T> lst;
   lst.curr = 0;
   cout << lst.n->info;
   lst.n->info = 0;
   lst.n->next = NULL;
   return lst;
}
```

If I remove the `cout << lst.n->info;` it causes a segmentation error. What I want to achieve is to simply create a List and have the next values:

lst:

- curr = 0
- n:

  - info = 0
  - next = NULL

But I can't find a way to achieve this, I tried searching on google and also reading about pointers and structures but I cannot find the problem. It might be a simple problem but I can't find it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you initialize `lst.n` ?

Comment: `lst.n` is empty or not inititialized, its value is random.

Comment: That's true I forgot to initialize lst.n, I'm so stupid. Thank you! It was a simple error after all hahaha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to initialize `lst.n`. Accessing uninitialized memory or a nullptr is undefined behavior.

You may do something like this:

```
List<T> listCreate()
{
   List<T> lst;
   lst.curr = 0;
   // new code
   lst.n = new Node<T>();
   lst.n->next = nullptr;
   // end
   cout << lst.n->info;
   lst.n->info = 0;
   lst.n->next = nullptr;
   return lst;
}
```

Please consider avoiding `NULL`. You should use `nullptr` in `c++`.

Comment: Thank you. I used NULL because I'm on a basic course of Algorithms and Data Structures and our professor told us to use NULL for now. Now I understand why the compiler complains about NULL and says "Converting from NULL to non-pointer type". Thank you, have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Remember dereferencing a null or uninitialized pointer is undefined behavior. You are trying to dereference an uninitialized pointer `lst.n->info` in your code.

Comment: It’s an uninitialised pointer, not necessarily a null pointer.

Comment: No problem - you can hit the `edit` button above and correct the answer for future readers.